How to Secure Protected Routes with JWT and Role-Based Authorization in ASP.NET Core?
I am currently working on implementing protected routes on a simple Web API.
But I can't seem to figure out how JWT works really. I am currently successfully creating and sending back the Token with:
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
            var foundUser = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == model.Username);
            if (foundUser == null) return BadRequest("Invalid Username or Password");
            var correctPassword = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(foundUser, model.Password);
            if (!correctPassword) return BadRequest("Invalid Username or Password");

            var token = await _tokenServices.CreateToken(foundUser);

            Response.Cookies.Append("auth_token", token, new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = false,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            });

            return Ok(new { message = "Logged In succesfully!" });

And the token itself gets created like so:
 public async Task<string> CreateToken(Usuario usuario)
        {

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,usuario.Id),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, usuario.UserName!),
            };
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(usuario);
            foreach (var role in userRoles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds,
                Issuer = _config["JWT:Issuer"]
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }

I am trying to implement my Protected routes through the use of Attibuttes within the Controllers:
    [HttpPost("create-new")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateRolesRequestDto model)
    {
        if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(model.Role)) return BadRequest("That role already exists");

        var newRole = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(model.Role.ToUpper()));
        if (newRole == null) return BadRequest("Invalid Input Data");

        return Ok(newRole);
    }
}

Now I understand there is probably something else to be done since I am using JWT to handle my Security but what? What else do I need in order to have protected Routes?
In case necessary this is the data that is seeded and used for the Users and its roles:
    builder.Entity<Persona>().HasData(
        new Persona
        {
            Id = 1,
            Nombre = "Ismael",
            ApellidoPaterno = "Moron",
            ApellidoMaterno = "Pedraza",
            Carnet = "12597382",
            Telefono = "75526864",
            UsuarioId = "1"
        }
    );


    var hasher = new PasswordHasher<Usuario>();
    builder.Entity<Usuario>().HasData(

        new Usuario
        {
            Id = "1",
            UserName = "ismael",
            Email = "ismaelmp997@hotmail.com",
            PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "123456"),
            PersonaId = 1
        }
    );

    List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>
    {
        new IdentityRole
        {
            Id= "1",
            Name="Admin",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
        },
        new IdentityRole
        {
            Id= "2",
            Name="User",
            NormalizedName = "User"
        }
    };

    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(roles);

    // Assign Admin Role to the User
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(
        new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            UserId = "1", // The Id of the Usuario
            RoleId = "1"  // The Id of the Admin role
        }
    );

As well as the whole of my Program.cs configuration:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);


builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<Usuario, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]!))
    };
});


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));

});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenServices, TokenServices>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapOpenApi();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();



app.Run();

I am still learning how to handle Authentication, Authorization and Role Based Access Control as a whole within .NET so any guidance or advice is more than welcome!
Some pics displaying the error and the successful login.

https://postimg.cc/PP9Nxn9K https://postimg.cc/xkydtJCF
https://postimg.cc/rRdMXKVT/4718a7f0


When Creating the Token use the method CreateJwtSecurityToken:
var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);
return jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

